# Retrieve item from object out of an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist

i'm trying to retrieve an item from an object that I stored in an ArrayList. Take a look at the code.

```
MyList.add(new Car(year,make,available));
```

Now i've stored a new car object to myList(arraylist). How can I get the make for example?

Thank you.

Comment: use `MyList.get(index).make;`

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking how to get a particular element from the list (by number? by something else?) or how to get the make when you've got a `Car` reference.

Comment: Is it really faster to ask people on SO about this than to open the first page of a Java reference?

Comment: @EvilDuck thank you for your comment. I find the Javadocs very hard to read since English isn't my native language.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate through the list with :

```
for (Car car : myList)
{
    car.getMake(); //if you added getter, if you had not you can use addedCar.make;
}
```

or you can just access one specific item using the index of the item :

```
Car addedCar = myList.get(0); // 0 because you want the first item.
addedCar.getMake(); //if you added getter, if you had not you can use addedCar.make;
```

Comment: Mark your post as solved if your problem is solved (check the green thumb at the left of an answer)

Answer (score 0):

1. As other answers mentioned before you can use MyList.get(index) but such way can be not good idea.
2. In your case I would suggest to use Map if you have some unique identifier for each Car object better to do Map in that case you will get efficient way to direct access to each Car object in your list
3. And for sure iterate over the list to get one element really bad idea from performance point of view.

My variant:

```
final Map<Integer, Car> myMap = new HashMap<>();
final Car newCar = new Car(year,make,available);
myMap.put(index, newCar); // where 'index' whatever you want that is unique for this collection year or brand or object ID

// get your object from collection
System.out.println(myMap.get(index)); // output is newCar
```